# How can I send a registration confirmation email with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, email-confirmation

I'm building a rails3 application (hosted on Heroku) and I'm using devise for user authentication. I would like to send a confirmation email every time a new user signs up to my app, that is confirming that he has successfully signed up etc.

**Note: I do not want to confirm his email address, i.e. I dont want to use the :confirmable devise module.**

Problem is, I cannot find any relevant ***devise*** or ***user*** controller action to add a mailer .deliver action.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about firing it off from your model (user.rb)?

```
#user.rb
after_create :some_method
def some_method
  YourMailerObject.deliver_some_message()
end
```

Comment: Hi Craig and thanks for your reply.

Indeed, what you suggest works fine. I'm trying to figure now how to pass the newly created user record to the action mailer class. I tried something like:

  after_create :send_newuser_emails
  def send_newuser_emails()
    Sender.signup_newuser_admin(self.username, self.email).deliver
  end

but the vars passed on are empty. Any ideas?

Comment: No problem, Alex! I believe that you only need to pass in self (i.e., YourMailerObject.deliver_some_message(self) to the mailer's deliver message because it's happening on the object itself after it's created. If you use a Ruby/Rails IDE (e.g., Aptana or RubyMine), you can debug pretty easily and see what 'self' contains inside that method at a breakpoint ... just a thought!

Comment: Hi Craig, 
Passing 'self' did the trick! Many thanks for your help!
PS: I use Aptana Studio 3, I tried to add a breakpoint but it does not work (i.e. the execution does not stop to inspect the line). Don't know what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Sweet! Glad that did it. I use Aptana Studio 3 as well. I recall some fun with getting debugging going ... in the Terminal view in Aptana, run gem list and make sure the output shows that the following gems are installed: 
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25 -- or whatever current version you might have)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)